# Group by Case Statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to group by the CASE statement but not having much luck. I have an orders table that I am trying to group the orders by total value for the month and categorise them based on their value.

```
 SELECT 
      CASE
          WHEN sum(order_total_price) IS NULL
            THEN 'Unknown'
          WHEN sum(order_total_price) <= 1000
            THEN 'Not more than 1,000'
          WHEN sum(order_total_price) <= 2000
            THEN 'Between 1,001 and 2000'
          WHEN sum(order_total_price) <= 3000
            THEN 'Between 2001 and 3000'
          WHEN sum(order_total_price) <= 4000
            THEN 'Between 3001 and 4000'
          WHEN sum(order_total_price) <= 5000
            THEN 'Between 4001 and 5000'
          ELSE 'Over 5000'
        END
          AS  total_sales,
        COUNT(*) as total
      FROM orders
      WHERE YEAR(order_time)=2014 and MONTH(order_time)=07

      GROUP BY total_sales
```

Comment: Luck doesn't have anything to do with. What matters is the specification. We'd expect the query in this question to return exactly one row. If it's not returning a row, then likely it's returning an error (though no mention of an error is made in the question.) SO we are left to guess that the resultset returned by the query does not satisfy some (as of yet unstated) requirement. Without even an example of the desired output, we can only take guess as to whether the statement is returning an error, or what the specification is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Jim Garrison said,

```
GROUP BY 1
```

would be best.

As an alternative, below will also work if you are not comfortable with numbers in group by. Put your original query without GROUP BY as inner query. Use the count and group by in an outer query.

```
  SELECT A.TOTAL_SALES, COUNT(1) FROM
  (SELECT 
      CASE
          WHEN sum(order_total_price) IS NULL
            THEN 'Unknown'
          WHEN sum(order_total_price) <= 1000
            THEN 'Not more than 1,000'
          WHEN sum(order_total_price) <= 2000
            THEN 'Between 1,001 and 2000'
          WHEN sum(order_total_price) <= 3000
            THEN 'Between 2001 and 3000'
          WHEN sum(order_total_price) <= 4000
            THEN 'Between 3001 and 4000'
          WHEN sum(order_total_price) <= 5000
            THEN 'Between 4001 and 5000'
          ELSE 'Over 5000'
        END
          AS  total_sales       
      FROM orders
      WHERE YEAR(order_time)=2014 and MONTH(order_time)=07

      ) AS A
      GROUP BY A.total_sales
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, the solution worked, i had to make an adjustment in the subquery and gorup by clients. Great!

Comment: Some potential performance issues to note: The functions on the column in the WHERE clause make it impossible for MySQL to make use of an index range scan operation with a suitable index. This query requires a full scan of *every* row in the table, so the functions can be evaluated. Secondly, this query requires MySQL to materialize the view query as a derived table, and then the outer query runs against the derived table. It's possible to obtain this same result with a query that doesn't require an intermediate derived table, and doesn't make a full scan necessary.

Comment: @spencer7593: I agree to your point. In my answer I have mentioned clearly that using column position is best. I only suggested alternate mechanism that it can also be done that way!

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand for this is

```
....
GROUP BY 1
```

Using the output column position.  Otherwise you'd have to repeat the entire `case` block in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Yes, MySQL allows for an expression in the SELECT list to be referenced in a GROUP BY clause by position within the SELECT list, but it also allows for the expression to be referenced by its alias; I don't see how replacing `GROUP BY total_sales` with `GROUP BY 1` makes any difference.

Comment: Hmm... MySQL seems to extend the standard, which does not allow the use of an alias here.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be returning a single row. Luck doesn't have anything do with it. What matters is the specification. And apart from the SQL query, it's not clear what resultset you want returned.

I'm guessing (and this is just a guess) that you want to return multiple rows, one for each of the order size categories derived by the CASE expression.

Perhaps the resultset returned by a query something like this:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN o.order_total_price IS NULL
         THEN 'Unknown'
       WHEN o.order_total_price <= 1000
         THEN 'Not more than 1,000'
       WHEN o.order_total_price <= 2000
         THEN 'Between 1,001 and 2000'
       WHEN o.order_total_price <= 3000
         THEN 'Between 2001 and 3000'
       WHEN o.order_total_price <= 4000
         THEN 'Between 3001 and 4000'
       WHEN o.order_total_price <= 5000
         THEN 'Between 4001 and 5000'
         ELSE 'Over 5000'
       END AS order_value_category 
     , SUM(o.order_total_price) AS total_sales
     , COUNT(*) AS count_sales
  FROM orders o
 WHERE o.order_time >= '2014-07-01' 
   AND o.order_time <  '2014-07-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
 GROUP BY order_value_category
```

---

For performance, to enable MySQL to make use of a suitable index to satisfy the predicate on the `order_time` category, we'd need to reference the "bare" `order_time` column in a range scan predicate.

Note that the GROUP BY clause implies an ORDER BY clause; if you want the rows returned in order other than by the derived `order_value_category` column, you'd need to specify a suitable `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GROUP BY, output rows are sorted according to the GROUP BY columns as if you had an ORDER BY for the same columns. To avoid the overhead of sorting that GROUP BY produces, add ORDER BY NULL:

SELECT a, COUNT(b) FROM test_table GROUP BY a ORDER BY NULL;
Relying on implicit GROUP BY sorting in MySQL 5.6 is deprecated. To achieve a specific sort order of grouped results, it is preferable to use an explicit ORDER BY clause. GROUP BY sorting is a MySQL extension that may change in a future release; for example, to make it possible for the optimizer to order groupings in whatever manner it deems most efficient and to avoid the sorting overhead.

http://academy.comingweek.com/sql-groupby-clause/